# Multiple different named images don't working in jquery magic 360 plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, 360-degrees

I have multiple images and they're named in different names and extension. I'm using magic 360 javascript plugin version 4.6.13. In frontend the page is show only tree.jpg. and magic360 dont working when I drag skin. in console Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getAttribute'). I made by [doc](https://www.magictoolbox.com/magic360/integration/#images)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>jQuery Integrated 360 Magic Spin Viewer</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/magic360.css">
    <script src="assets/js/magic360.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <style type="text/css">
        #gallery {
            width: 500px; /* Adjust the width as needed */
            height: 400px; /* Adjust the height as needed */
            margin: 0 auto;
        }

        .magic360 {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
        }
    </style>

    <div id="gallery">
        <a class="Magic360" data-options="images: images/nature/tree.jpg images/nature/mountain.webp">
            <img src="images/nature/tree.jpg">
        </a>
    </div>

<!-- Your HTML content here -->
<script>
    var Magic360Options = {
        columns: 6
    };
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code specifies 2 images in the `images` setting:

```
<a class="Magic360" data-options="images: images/nature/tree.jpg images/nature/mountain.webp">
```

But your `columns` setting is set to 6:

```
var Magic360Options = {
columns: 6
};
```

To solve this, you can either specify 6 images in the `images` setting or change the `columns` setting to 2.

Comment: I changed it but it's not working. it returns error

Comment: There will be a problem in your code. What's the URL of your page, to see the issue?